# How do I select the number of an incoming SMS?

Tags: sms, google-hangouts, copy-paste, spam

I received some SMSes that show up both in my SMS app and in Google Hangouts; however for the life of me I can't figure out how to just *copy* that number (in order to report it as a spammer), short of either adding it to my contacts (I don't want to) or writing it down on a piece of paper and re-entering it (which seems just plain silly).

Googling around, it seems there are quite a few SMS/MMS applications in the wild and I can't tell which one exactly mine is (it says "Version 4.1.1", but I can't find an ID), but I would expect either it or google hangouts to have that functionality *somewhere* ... so what am I missing?

(the obvious things - long press, short press, double click etc. on the number do nothing, and the menus only show me options for blocking the sender or adding it to my contacts)

Comment: Hint: For identification of the SMS app you're using, it might help to name your device and Android version, plus adding a screenshot (the latter especially when that app didn't come pre-installed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Google Hangouts, if I click the contact bubble (the circle on the right where their picture would be) it brings up their contact card. If you long-click the number there, there's an option to copy it to the clipboard.

**NOTE:** you may need to add the number as a contact to view the number in the "contact card."

Comment: Yep, that worked, and I didn't need to add the number as a contact. Thanks a lot!